How to Import Power Queries from an Excel file on Sharepoint to Power BI?
I'm trying to import Power Queries from a workbook developed and saved on Sharepoint, which uses data saved on Sharepoint, to a new Power BI file.
Following instructions at
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-import-excel-workbooks
but after receiving the popup showing check marks indicating my migration is completed with queries checked, I also get a yellow warning bar saying "there are pending changes in your queries that haven't been applied".

I hit "Apply Changes" and a message flashes up which says something about loading, but then nothing appears in my tables / data / model view.
Is this some problem because I need to authenticate with Sharepoint somehow?
